# How to concatenate two vectors without overlapping parts in java

Tags: java, vector

I want a method that removes overlapping parts of two vectors of the same type, then concatenates and returns.

```
public static Vector<?> concatenateVector(Vector<?> baseVector, Vector<?> additionVector) {
    if (baseVector.getClass().equals(additionVector.getClass())) {
        additionVector.removeAll(baseVector);
        baseVector.addAll((Collection<?>) additionVector);
        return baseVector;
    } else
        return null;

}
```

but occured error :

```
The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#3-of ?>) in the type Vector<capture#3-of ?>  
is not applicable for the arguments (Vector<capture#4-of ?>)
```

Switching from `Vector` to `Collection`, still has the same problem.

Maybe there is another good way?

Comment: Huh, what is that getClass() going to achieve for you? I think you want to learn about type erasure. Your code does NOT at all check whether the ENTRIES of your vectors have the same class?

Comment: And of course, why return null, instead of some empty vector? And why use vectors in the first place?!

Comment: I'm returning null because I'm worried about the types of the two vectors being different, but using baseVector.getClass () is a mistake. haha

Comment: Unless you are using your own Vector class, the class of these two containers is the same. But again: do research on Java generics and type erasure. The information about the exact type of entries isn't available at runtime any more.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I don't understand the last sentence. Do you have any links?

Comment: I totally agree with you, but my owner doesn't give me time to do that OTL haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the wildcard to generic type.

```java
public static <T> Vector<T> concatenateVector(Vector<T> baseVector, Vector<T> additionVector) {

    additionVector.removeAll(baseVector)
    baseVector.addAll(additionVector);
    return baseVector;
}
```

I remove getClass, because both return vector, this validation is not necessary with generic types.

```java
if (baseVector.getClass().equals(additionVector.getClass())) {
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Validation was useless, because if the types were different, there would be an error in removeAll().

Answer (score 1):

One way is to move from wildcard to parameterized type.

```
public static <T> Vector<T> concatenateVector(Vector<T> baseVector, Vector<T> additionVector) {
    if (baseVector.getClass().equals(additionVector.getClass())) {
      additionVector.removeAll(baseVector);
      baseVector.addAll(additionVector);
      return baseVector;
    } else
      return null;

  }
```

Comment: But the real question remains: what is that getClass() and equals() supposed to achieve?!

Comment: thank your help, I had to use <T> instead of <?>,  Can you tell me the names of these? It is Type?